# apt is always locked in other duties when I want to update my system

Tags: debian, apt, process

Very often when I want to `update` one of my systems, `apt` is "locked" by other processes.  It can happen more than once the same day.  I have to run this command and `kill` the top process to get `apt` back, but I shouldn't have this problem, I never have before.

When I do `apt update` I get this:

```
root ~ # apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

My system is Debian stretch 9.8, and I install all updates.  I use the KDE Plasma Desktop.

```
root ~ # ps aux | grep apt
_apt     25783  9.0  0.1  64300 24956 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25784  8.9  0.1  64300 25032 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25785  8.9  0.2 206296 35636 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     25786  9.0  0.2 206300 35532 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     25787  9.0  0.1  64300 25012 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25788  8.9  0.1  64300 25008 ?        S    10:12   0:58 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25789  9.1  0.1  64300 25192 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25790  9.1  0.1  64300 24984 ?        S    10:12   0:59 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     25817  4.8  0.1  56876 21644 ?        S    10:14   0:28 /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
_apt     25818  4.8  0.2 206296 35568 ?        S    10:14   0:28 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     25820  4.7  0.2 206304 35636 ?        S    10:14   0:27 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     26426  0.0  0.1  56876 19752 ?        S    10:22   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
_apt     26427  0.0  0.0   4276  1656 ?        S    10:22   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/apt-key --quiet --readonly verify --status-fd 3 /tmp/apt.sig.LTumm1 /tmp/apt.data.hNgDBV
_apt     26511  104  0.0  38092  8508 ?        R    10:23   0:03 apt-config shell GPGV Apt::Key::gpgvcommand
root     26513  0.0  0.0  12788  1000 pts/1    S+   10:23   0:00 grep apt
```

QUESTION:

**I don't understand what this means what is apt doing and how to fix it?**

EDIT:

[pstree -a](https://pastebin.com/U56qEDcx)

```
root ~ # apt list packagekit
Listing... Done
packagekit/stable,stable,now 1.1.5-2+deb9u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

---

```
root ~ # apt list aptdaemon
Listing... Done
```

Comment: please date the problem: edit the question to include the name and version of your OS, and also the full version of `apt` shown by the command `dpkg-query -s apt`.

Comment: @sourcejedi for weeks and today

Comment: I mean, run `pstree -a` when you have the problem.  you don't have the problem right now this minute, do you?

Comment: @sourcejedi yes I have the problem right this minute, I didn't fix it with killing the head process yet so it still holds apt hostage

Comment: surely `pstree` should be showing all these same `apt` sub-processes that `ps aux` shows?  then you can find the parent process.  no?

Comment: @sourcejedi   `root ~ # apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Comment: If you don't want to work out what is happening with `pstree`, just look at `grep PPid /proc/PID/`, where PID is the process number for one of the guilty apt sub-processes.  PPid tells you the parent PID.

Comment: @sourcejedi yes gui kde

Comment: The `pkmon` command will show current PackageKit actions, and their progress.  The type of actions is show in a line "role", this may be `refresh-cache`, `get-updates`, `search-details`, `update-packages`.  `update-packages` will be shown even if PK has been asked to only download updates, and not install them yet.

Comment: @sourcejedi I had to restart the system because everyting was freezing up and now I don't have this active apt in hostage, but be sure it comes back

Comment: @sourcejedi `root ~ # pkmon
Transactions:
 [none]
daemon connected=1
network status=online`

Comment: Are you using Synaptic? Because Synaptic locks apt

Comment: @stackzebra no I never use synaptic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer details so far:

Because your `ps` output shows no `/usr/bin/apt-get` (or `/usr/bin/apt`) command, the apt sub-processes must be started by some other process.  The process must be using the `libapt` library.  You should really make sure what this parent process is, e.g. by looking at the process hierarchy in `pstree`.  But the only possibility I know here would be `packagekitd`, the PackageKit daemon.

To be fair to the PackageKit daemon, I think it only works in response to requests - e.g. from gnome-software, pk-update-icon - or from KDE Plasma (KDE "Apper" program ?)

It is a known limitation that PackageKit actions on Debian will conflict with the `apt` command.  It is also expected that a good GUI will periodically check for security updates, so it can remind you to install them.  I am sorry to say this is not a perfect combination!

However, it is *not* expected that this happens "always".  Usually you will not be doing background PackageKit actions all the time.  Especially on a stable version of Debian like you are running.  Debian does not release a lot of updates e.g. compared to Fedora Linux, and `apt update` is quite fast and efficient when there are no updates.

If you have this problem very often, you might have some problem that is making `apt` take a lot of time, or somehow making `apt`, PackageKit, or your GUI system keep retrying a lot.

---

PackageKit originates from RedHat.  In RedHat-based distributions like Fedora Linux, I know that PackageKit is able to run "background" actions e.g. to check for updates automatically.  And the background action should get cancelled automatically, when the user starts asking PackageKit to do something.  I do not know whether Debian+Apper works like this or not.

You could *try* to ask PackageKit for a "foreground" update, by either using Apper or `pkcon refresh force` + `pkcon upgrade` instead of `apt update` + `apt upgrade`.  Upgrading through PackageKit is slightly different to `apt upgrade`, because PackageKit does not ask for package settings, and it does not ask whether you want to keep your modified configuration files, overwrite them with packaged changes, or try to merge them together.

Comment: it solved my problems by removing apper and packagekitd.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these commands, 
If you are not root then try with `sudo` command ,

```
pkill apt && apt update
```

I'm not sure about this command. This will kill apt processes running on system.